# After post request, continue checking for completion | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, async-await, request-promise

I'm making a post request with a good amount of data that will take about a minute to finish saving. The hosting service I'm using for this will time out requests after 5 seconds, so I need to set this up to periodically check if the data saving is complete to give a final update.

I'm using `request-promise`, and have looked at both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` approaches. In my latest attempt (below) I'm using a `setTimeout` approach, but my second `then` keeps being called pretty much immediately. I want this to hang out in the first `then` stage until it's checked a bunch of times (24 here) or actually finished.

I might have a totally wrong approach here, but I'm not finding examples of the thing I'm trying to reference. Any direction to a good example of this or where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function checkFiles () {
  return request({
    uri: `${process.env.ROOT_URL}/api/v1/get/file-processing`,
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
  })
    .then(res => { return res; })
    .catch(err => { return err; });
}

async function init () {
  const filesPostOptions = {/* request options */};

  await request(filesPostOptions)
    .then(async status => { // THEN #1
      if (status.status === 201) {
        return status;
      }

      let checks = 0;

      const checkIt = function() {
        checks++;
        checkFiles()
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 201 || checks > 24) {
              status = res;
              return status;
            } else {
              setTimeout(checkIt, 5000);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      };

      checkIt();
    })
    .then(status => { // THEN #2
      if (!status.status) {
        throw Error('Post request timed out.');
      }

      return status;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      err = err.error ? err.error : err;
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

The post response will deliver a response with a `status` property (the status code) and a `message` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control the return in `"THEN #"` by adding a `Promise`:

```
.then(async status => { // THEN #1
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <---- prevent an immediate return
    if (status.status === 201) {
      return resolve(status);
    }

    let checks = 0;

    const checkIt = function() {
      checks++;
      checkFiles()
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 201 || checks > 24) {
            status = res;
            resolve(status);
          } else {
            setTimeout(checkIt, 1000);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    };

    checkIt();
  })
})
```